# Was Sariputta alive during the time of Buddha's death?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, sutras, death

I have found two Suttas and I am a bit confused about Sariputta's death.

In [DN 16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato), there is a part about Sariputta being alive at the time of Buddha's death. (look at 4. Sāriputta’s Lion’s Roar in DN 16)

In this sutta [SN 47.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn47/sn47.014.nypo.html), Buddha talks about the death of Sariputta and Maha Moggallana. "This assembly, O bhikkhus, appears indeed empty to me, now that Sariputta and Maha Moggallana have passed away."

What is the correct timeline? Why was Sariputta alive during Buddha's parinibbana in DN 16?

Answer (score 5):

Time in DN 16, MahaParinibbanaSutta, is already clear for the Sutta Pali memorizer, but it's hard for the reader because it's too long for skipping reading. Memorizing with the memorized & enlightened monk is the way to study tipitaka faster&easier really really.

In DN 16...

1. Ven.Sariputta's Lion's Roar (no. 16) comes first story,
2. then the Buddha spends the last rainy season (Vassa)  in the village
   of Beluva, Vesali (no. 27) ([Ven.Sariputta died 15 days after that season](https://84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=13&A=6242)),
3. then the buddha announced his dead date 3 months after that last
   rainy season (no. 46).

As we knew whether Sariputta died 6 months, fullmoon day on 12th month, before the Buddha died, full moon day on 6th month. The Buddha announced his dead date 3 months before the death, **so Ven. Sariputta died before the Buddha 6 months.**